# Android Studio - проблема с анимацией на разных устройствах

Tags: android, анимация, масштабирование, экран, устройства

Моя проблема заключается в том, что на разных устройствах элементы после анимации имеют различное расположение и размер. Если на первом устройстве всё в порядке, то уже на втором элементы располагаются далеко друг от друга и немного меньше в размере. Анимация перемещения указана в процентах от родителя (экрана), а анимация  масштабирования - в dp. Вот пример:
[image: Разметка с анимацией]

Первое устройство, на котором всё как надо:
[image: 1080x1920, 480dpi]

Второе устройство, на котором всё не так, как хотелось бы:
[image: 1440x2560, 560dpi]
Прошу, помогите!

Comment: А почему не указать скэйл в процентах?